# styles.less unable to get content

Tags: magento-2.1, css

I have been having an issue with my `magento 2.1.8` webstore in which the styles.less for the admin pages is not being generated.

I am receiving this error when i try to do a static-content:deploy

`adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/css/styles.less
Unable to get content for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_Checkout/css/                    source/module/_checkout.less'`

The Magento_Checkout module has been overwritten in my current theme, and i have placed the `_checkout.less` from the original module in the overwritten module in `css/source/module/` but the error is still occurring.

What would be the correct location to place this file?

EDIT:

it seems I am missing a folder:

`adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_Checkout`

This folder is not appearing at all in the `static/adminhtml/magento/backend/en_GB` directory when i run `static-content:deploy`

How do i make this folder appear?

Thanks

EDIT 2:

after commenting out the line:

```
@import '../Magento_Checkout/css/source/_module.less';
```

in `styles.less` I have found that the issue is not with the magento checkout, it is with the imports for all the modules:

```
// @import '../Magento_Checkout/css/source/_module.less';
// @import '../Ess_M2ePro/css/source/_module.less';
// @import '../Magento_AdminNotification/css/source/_module.less';
// @import '../Magento_AdvancedCheckout/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Backend/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Banner/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Braintree/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Catalog/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_CatalogPermissions/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Config/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_ConfigurableProduct/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_CurrencySymbol/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Customer/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_CustomerBalance/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Downloadable/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_GiftCard/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_GiftRegistry/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_GiftWrapping/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Marketplace/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_ProductVideo/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Review/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Reward/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Rma/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Sales/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Shipping/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Staging/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Tax/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Translation/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Ui/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Vault/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_VersionsCms/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_VisualMerchandiser/css/source/_module.less';
```

When saving and uploading this file, i get the same error message but for the `Magento_Backend` module:

`Compilation from source:
adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/css/styles.less
Unable to get content for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_Backend/css/source/_module.less'`

I have a feeling this may be an issues with the permissions? has anyone had this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying to overwrite **Magento_Checkout** in the backend theme, which is intended for admin.

You must do this overwriting in your current theme.

Your current theme is in `/app/design/frontend/PackageName/ThemeName`, where you can put the **Magento_Checkout** folder and the `_checkout.less` file is in this path `/app/design/frontend/PackageName/ThemeName/Magento_Checkout/web/css/source/module/_checkout.less`

Comment: cheers for your answer. while trying to find a solution, i tidied up some of my files. the Magento_Checkout module does not need to be over written. I have updated my question with the current problem

Comment: I think it's a confusion, please tell me what the result you want to have. Do you want the result in the **frontend**, in the **backend** *(admin)*?

Comment: The `styles.less` file is a file for the **backend** theme *(admin)* where you can import stylesheet files from all backend modules, and this `styles.less` the file is compiled and generates the `styles.css` file.